# Update timestamp column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table structure

```
create table t_test(
  id int ,
  timestamp timestamp
)
```

Fill data

```
insert into t_test(id)values(1)
```

Query result

```
select * from t_test
------------------------
id | timestamp
------------------------
1  | 0x0000000000024EBC
------------------------
```

Add column

```
alter table t_test add column new_column char(1) default '1' with values
```

After I add column, the column timestamp value has changed. How can I do and keep it value like before?

Query result (after add column)

```
select * from t_test
----------------------------
id | timestamp | new_column
----------------------------
1  | 0x0000000000024EBC | 1
----------------------------
```

Thanks

Comment: I would not recommend using "timestamp" as a column (or any) name

Comment: @PaulMaxwell Thank you! PaulMaxwell.  This's a old project and complex bussines system, no way .

Comment: Are you aware of what `timstamp` actually is? It's a rowversion number, not a `datetime`

Comment: Short answer - you can't. That value is maintained by the database engine and you cannot force it to be any particular value nor can you disable how the engine updates it.